# pre selected Option from array

Tags: angularjs

I dug a few hours without finding an answer to what i want to do. I'm working on a complicate form with a lot of variables, so i'll try to narrow my request here :)

```
var list = [{id:0, name:opt0}, {id:1, name:opt1},{id:2, name:opt2}];
var selected = ['opt1', 'opt2'];
var numberOfRows = 2;
```

I got a variable number of select based on a variable. So i use ng-repeat like this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in numberOfRows track by $index">
  <td>
    <select list.indexOf(selected[$index]) as item for item in list></select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

the result should be like this

```
<tr><td>
  <select>
    <option label="opt0" value="opt0"></option>
    <option label="opt1" value="opt1" selected="selected"></option>
    <option label="opt2" value="opt2"></option>
  </select>
</tr></td>
  <tr><td>
  <select>
    <option label="opt0" value="opt0"></option>
    <option label="opt1" value="opt1"></option>
    <option label="opt2" value="opt2" selected="selected"></option>
  </select>
</tr></td>
```

I tried many way to write my ng-option.
what i have actually is the correct number of select with the list inside each of them, but each select should have a different pre selected variable. And they all are selected on the last value of my list. No matter what i try.

ps: the values in my array 'selected' are always in the list[$index].name

If someone knows how to achieve that i will be very happy ^^

....

little side request : Is it possible to do a filter on the list which will remove/hide the selected option trough all the selects? 
result like this :

```
<tr><td>
  <select>
    <option label="opt0" value="opt0"></option>
    <option label="opt1" value="opt1" selected="selected"></option>
    //opt2 removed because it's selected in another select
  </select>
</tr></td>
  <tr><td>
  <select>
    <option label="opt0" value="opt0"></option>
    //opt1 removed because it's selected in the previous select
    <option label="opt2" value="opt2" selected="selected"></option>
  </select>
</tr></td>
```

thanks :)

Comment: Probably a typo but you are missing a space before `selected` in your first one. `value="opt1"selected="selected"`

Comment: just typo in my request. my variables are very long name.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your existing solution on the first part, but i don't know how you manage to make this line of code work:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in numberOfRows track by $index">
```

So i did my own version just basing on your desired output, using `$scope.selected` as the ng-model array, as you can see i am mutating your `$scope.selected` to have a value of `[{id:1, name:'opt1'},{id:2, name:'opt2'}]` which are the complete object preselected value of `['opt1', 'opt2']`.

```
$scope.list = [{id:0, name:'opt0'}, {id:1, name:'opt1'},{id:2, name:'opt2'}]; 
$scope.selected = ['opt1', 'opt2'];
$scope.selectModels = [];
var newSelected = [];
angular.forEach($scope.selected, function(value, key) {
            this.push($filter("filter")($scope.list, {name: value})[0]);
}, newSelected);
$scope.selectModels = newSelected;
```

And you markup:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in selected">
  <td>
    <select ng-model="selectModels[$index]" ng-options="option.name for option in list track by option.id" class="form-control"></select>
    {{ selectModels[$index] }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

I think your side question is possible if you generate a different `list` for each row, or use `options-disabled` for that row.

Here is working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebautistajr/3ps5xd4w/) hope this helps. You can set a new question of your side request.

Comment: Not bad, but how come we can't select opt0 in any select in your fiddle?

Do i have to use $scope only? because my controller header is like this
    .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope){
      var vm = this;
    });

Comment: Sorry i did a quick fix, fiddle if working now, just added few variables and change the ng-options value.